# What would be the dimension of this subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $F = \bigl\langle(1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2, −1), (2, 1, 0, 3)\bigr\rangle$. It has a three dimensional basis. However, if I find the linear equations that yield it, I get:

$F = {(x, y, z, t) / x-2y+z=0; 2x-y-t=0}$ . These appear to be correct as per the solution of the problem.

I thought the dimension of a subspace was equal to the dimension of the vector space it's in (in this case, 4) minus the number of linear equations that define it (so $4-2=2$ ). However the dimension of a subspace is also the minimum number of vectors that can generate it. In other words, it's the number of vectors in the basis, which is 3.

Can someone help me find out what's wrong here? I suspect the quick "dimension of the vector space - linear equations" formula might not be correct, at least not always.

Comment: The three vectors generating $\;F\;$ are linearly **dependent**, as you can prove easily by any means you've learned.

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh, so it's not really a basis, just a regular set of vectors. Makes sense, thanks.